# How to install various applications derived from base app

Tags: android

I have an app (let's call it BaseApp) which is some sort, as the name implies, of a base app.

A client buys our app, so I have to change some minor things (colors, titles, background and icons pngs, that sort of things).

Is there any way I can install the base app AND the client app in the same phone?

I have changed the name of the base folder, and in `AndroindManifest.xml` I changed the package of the app, but if I install the client app it overwrites the BaseApp.

How can I achieve this goal?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using gradle? If yes, did you change the package name in the gradle settings as well?

Comment: No, I didn't. Checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have changed the name of the base folder, and in AndroindManifest.xml I changed the package of the app, but if I install the client app it overwrites the BaseApp.

Don't do that.

> A client buys our app, so I have to change some minor things (colors, titles, background and icons pngs, that sort of things).

Have one project for the app. Have one [product flavor](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) per customer, plus probably a "generic" one that you use for testing.

> Is there any way I can install the base app AND the client app in the same phone?

In your product flavors, use `applicationIdSuffix` to put a per-client suffix on the application IDs. The application ID is what makes an app unique; having unique suffixes means that each of your client's apps is unique. You need this for the Play Store or other distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [build variants & flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).

It is a really handy mechanism when you only have a few things that should change between two versiosn of your app.

You can define them with different appIds so they can be installed side by side on the same device.